# Excel VBA: ranges to xml files

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to accomplish in Excel is the following:
Excel sheet is given with fixed values: (keys A1:C1 / values A2:C2) , and DATA: (A5:variable)
Required output is different XML files per DATA value.

[image: Drawing]

I cannot figure out the right vbscript syntax. But it should do something like:

1. Get fixed values into an associative array or dictionary
2. Loop through the data (until blank line)
3. Create new structure where fixed values and data are combined
4. Output to separate XML files (new file per data element).

Someone who can show this in VBA syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this is not complete answer, but the main idea...

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToXml()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim wsh As Worksheet, sTmp As String
    
    
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    i = 5
    Do While wsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
        Debug.Print "=== new file here ==="
        'key1 & key2
        sTmp = ""
        For j = 0 To 1
            sTmp = sTmp & "<" & wsh.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=j) & ">" & wsh.Range("A2").Offset(ColumnOffset:=j) & _
                "</" & wsh.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=j) & ">" & vbCrLf
        Next j
        'data
        sTmp = sTmp & "<" & wsh.Range("A4") & ">" & wsh.Range("A" & i) & "</" & wsh.Range("A4") & ">" & vbCrLf
        'key 3
            sTmp = sTmp & "<" & wsh.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=2) & ">" & wsh.Range("A2").Offset(ColumnOffset:=2) & _
                "</" & wsh.Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=2) & ">"
        Debug.Print sTmp
        Debug.Print
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Result:

```
=== new file here ===
<KEY1>VAL1</KEY1>
<KEY2>VAL2</KEY2>
<DATA>DATA1</DATA>
<KEY3>VAL3</KEY3>

=== new file here ===
<KEY1>VAL1</KEY1>
<KEY2>VAL2</KEY2>
<DATA>DATA2</DATA>
<KEY3>VAL3</KEY3>

=== new file here ===
<KEY1>VAL1</KEY1>
<KEY2>VAL2</KEY2>
<DATA>DATA3</DATA>
<KEY3>VAL3</KEY3>
```

All you need to do is to change the script to your needs. ;)

Comment: Thanks Maciej. This is really a good start. I'll be able to extend from here.

Comment: You're very welcome. BTW: the best THANKS is when you accept an answer and upvote it. ;)